# Add overlaping trendline in a scatterplot, SPSS

Tags: graph, spss

I'm trying to visualize big chunks of panel data over multiple years. I would like to add a mean total to my graphs, to visualize the deviation of the individual trends from the mean total. This is my current syntax in which I visualize the 10 IDs (out of 100) with the lowest income from 2011 to 2018. I would like to add the mean of the total IDs (100) to the graph:

```
* scatterplot with trendlines for desos.
GGRAPH
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=year inc ID MISSING=LISTWISE 
    REPORTMISSING=NO
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE
  /FITLINE TOTAL=NO SUBGROUP=YES.
BEGIN GPL
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset"))
  DATA: year=col(source(s), name("Year"))
  DATA: inc=col(source(s), name("inc"))
  DATA: ID=col(source(s), name("ID"), unit.category())
  GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("Year"))
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("inc"))
  GUIDE: legend(aesthetic(aesthetic.color.interior), label("ID"))
  GUIDE: text.title(label("Trend of incomes for income group 10 of 10 over time"))
  ELEMENT: point(position(Year*inc), color.interior(ID))
END GPL.
```

Is there a posibility to add another element to the plot, in this case the variable mean_inc_total?